# Tab output behavior within a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I try to be as punctilious as possible in researching before I ask a question, especially one so simple, so bear with me.

I have a String that's tab delimited, and when I output it to a JTextArea in Java, I get behavior that looks like this:

```
FirstName   LastName   PhoneNumber         BirthDate
```

Linewrap is turned off with horizontal scrolling enabled. After toiling over the documentation and SA, I'm missing something obvious as to why it's exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the String contains tabs, so what do you expect?

Comment: Explain to my lowly self why the fact that the String contains tabs makes this obvious, if you would?

Comment: Idle speculation: a positive [duck test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test).

Answer (score 1):

As @kleopatra comments, this is not unexpected. As alternatives, consider [`JTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jtable/info) or [*How to Use HTML in Swing Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Addendum: I previously overlooked [`setTabSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setTabSize%28int%29).

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509429 */
public class TextAreaTabs extends JPanel {

    public TextAreaTabs() {
        JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("FirstName\tLastName\tPhoneNumber\tBirthDate");
        jta.setTabSize(10);
        this.add(jta);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TextAreaTabs");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TextAreaTabs().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd tried setTabSize before with no luck. Must be some other issue. I hate to use a JTable for something this simple. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Edit your question to include additional details; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may help.